# recordset.movefirst "Rowset position cannot be restarted"

Tags: vba, excel, ado

I have a function that runs a stored procedure that returns only a single row and column (so one result).

I'm trying to get that one result into a variable so I can return it. I'm trying to use `recordset.MoveFirst` but I get the "Rowset position cannot be restarted." error. I tried just removing it, since I only have one result, but I then get an overflow. My statement looks like this:

```
If recordset.EOF = False Then
    recordset.MoveFirst
    temp = rs!ID 
 End IF
```

`temp` is an integer. I've checked the stored procedure to make sure it only returns the single result, and it does. Am I doing something wrong? Is there a better way to pass the result into a variable? It's possible the recordset is forward only (which means it's read only?) but I can't seem to find an answer as to how to fix that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is usually no reason to `MoveFirst` if you have not previously navigated the record set.

The `overflow` is unrelated to the database code and is caused by  `rs!ID` not fitting in a VBA `integer` (16 bit) so make `temp` a `Long`  instead (32 bit) and remove `MoveFirst`.

Comment: That did it! Thanks. Can you explain why an `integer` wouldn't work? Is it something with `ADO` and `SQL`?

Comment: VBA has old roots and its `integer` type is only 16 bits in size meaning it can only store numbers in the range of +/-32767. If you try to assign it a larger value it will `overflow`. The `Long` type is 32-bits wide so has a larger range (2140000000 and change). A `Long` is size compatible with most databases `Int` type.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are not using a forward-only recordset. Recordsets are this way by default. Instead use a dynamic (adOpenDynamic) or static (adOpenStatic) cursor type.

You may also need to set `CursorLocation = adUseClient`.

Finally, check for `BOF` before calling `MoveFirst`.

Example:

```
...
rs.CursorType = adOpenStatic
rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rs.Open "SELECT * FROM MyTable"
...

If (Not rs.BOF) Then
    rs.MoveFirst
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use MoveFirst for forward only recordset ONLY when you are at EOF.
Tricky, undocumented, but WORKS!!!!

Comment: Undocumented behavior is not guaranteed to be carried forward as new versions are released so buyer beware.